# Form.ShowDialog with Excel as owner is slow

Tags: c#, winforms, interop

I'm working on an Excel add-in and I have a form (WinForms) that I would like to be modal, and show center parent.  I'm assigning the Excel's handle to a `NativeWindow`, and then using that as the `owner` argument when I call `ShowDialog`.  Looks something like this:

```
NativeWindow excel = new NativeWindow();
excel.AssignHandle(new IntPtr(application.Hwnd)); // interop Excel app
MyWindow window = new Window();
window.ShowDialog(excel);
```

The call to `ShowDialog` here takes ~5 seconds.  If I simply call `ShowDialog` normally, all the other code intact, it comes up immediately — so I'm reasonably confident that's the culprit.

Am I doing something stupid here?  Are there events or lazy loading going on under the hood (or with Excel itself) that I could kick off earlier?

Comment: There is no obvious reason why this would be slow, beyond Excel thinking about it for a while.  ShowDialog() is already pretty good at picking the right window as the owner automatically, it uses GetActiveWindow().

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/8098961/880990 for a possible solution.