# Pressing "OK" on an OpenFileDialog takes a long time

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to select a file name from a share with a file dialog (for example `OpenFileDialog`).

Clicking "OK" on the dialog took a long time (up to 20 seconds in my case). This is also true, if I navigate to the share folder before pressing "OK". It seems as if pressing "OK" triggers a download or something similar.

- How can I speed up pressing "OK" on the `OpenFileDialog`. (Maybe it indeed triggers a download and I can tell it not to, etc.)
- Is there another dialog I should use instead to select a file? (Maybe `OpenFileDialog` implies that the file is opened and there is a select dialog.)

This is my code:

```
var openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog()
{
  InitialDirectory = "c:\\",
  Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.tca|All files (*.*)|*.*",
  FilterIndex = 2,
  RestoreDirectory = true,
};

if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
  MessageBox.Show(openFileDialog1.FileName);
}
```

This is the backtrace, while the dialog is busy:

```
  [Managed to Native Transition] 
  System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.FileDialog.RunDialogVista(System.IntPtr hWndOwner) + 0x75 Bytes       
  System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.FileDialog.RunDialog(System.IntPtr hWndOwner) + 0x55 Bytes        
  System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.CommonDialog.ShowDialog(System.Windows.Forms.IWin32Window owner) + 0x1cb Bytes    
  System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.CommonDialog.ShowDialog() + 0x7 Bytes     
> TestCases.exe!TestCases.Program.SelectFile() Line 39 + 0xa Bytes
  TestCases.exe!TestCases.Program.Main() Line 24 + 0x5 Bytes
```

Comment: Do you experiment this both in release & debug mode?

Comment: @Thomas I tested both, no difference as far as I can tell.

Comment: Do you browse the network by WiFi? Ethernet? Do you see this behavior when you browse the network or only with OpenFileDialog?

Comment: No, it doesn't automatically download the file. `OpenFileDialog` is only a thin wrapper around the Windows dialog - it hardly has any code. As for the Windows dialog, well, it does plenty of things. For example, it can dereference shortcuts for you (that might take a sec, but 20s is a stretch). What do you see if you break the debugger while the dialog is "hung"? Are you somewhere in windows APIs, or in your code?

Comment: I have no problem reading an entire file from a shared server placed internally on our network. Using OpenFileDialog.

Could it be that the file you are trying to locate, is on a ftp or perhaps some other place that requires authentications of some sort?

Comment: @Max Mazur From what I can tell, it is a normal file on a normal windows share requiring normal user authentication.

Comment: OpenFileDialog loads a *lot* of code into your process.  Code you did not write, shell extensions that you have installed on your machine.  You can only see what it does by enabling unmanaged code debugging.  SysInternals' AutoRuns is a good tool to disable them and find the evildoer.

Answer (score 1):

The fix which worked for me was adding the option 'SupportMultiDottedExtensions '

```
var OpenFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog
{
    ...
    SupportMultiDottedExtensions = true
};
```

I had two possible file extensions and without this option, it was taking 5-10 seconds to respond to clicking on the 'OK' button.

Answer (score -1):

Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751188/openfiledialog-c-slow-on-any-file-better-solution) link for a solution. Others has had the same problem. Explaining old shortcuts/webshortcuts could have an impact on this.

Hope this helps you.